# Empty Excel Chart causes error message "one or more invalid references" after deleting data from worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-charts, vba

Who could provide some help in avoiding this error ?

**Description:**

1. I create a chart (x-y plot) containing 1 series of data.
2. I delete this series.
3. I delete the columns of data holding the source data which has been
   used for the (already deleted) series. 
   Now the error message mentioned above occurs !

**Question:**
What element do I have to delete from the chart additional to the series in order to avoid this message ?

**What I already tried:**

1. The original error was occuring during running a VBA macro. The
   message is not coming from VBA --> I can reproduce the error with a
   clean workbook, adding a chart manually and removing the series
   manually. So it seems to be a general Excel issue.
2. In the Macro, I tried to add `activechart.refresh` and
   `activechart.chartarea.clearcontents` and `activechart.legend.clear`
   after deleting the series, before leaving the macro. No success
3. In this forum there are some similar questions, but the answers
   listed here are not really solving my problem (as far as I could
   see so far)
4. There is no other Chart pointing to the deleted data
5. Setting the datasource property of the chart to "Nothing" is crashing Excel.. don't try this
6. Hiding one series which remains every time in the chart might be a workaround (thanks to 'Excel Developers'). I'm not able to try it fast, as that would need a quite big amount of reprogramming.
7. setting the datasource property of the chart to a reference to an empty cell after deleting the last series seems to bring improvement, but no solution. From time to time the error is coming back.
   Ihave to find out exactly when :-(
8. Instead of deleting the last remaining series, I used `activechart.chartarea.clearcontents`. This solves the issue for some type of Charts. But unfortunately not for all. At this point I have to give up... The error is not critical and won't occur too often.

Any other idea / suggestion ?
Looking forward to your answers / suggestions /hints

Comment: Sounds to me that you want to create a plot chart with a series of data, and have the data being non visible after you had the chart?

Comment: Alex, thanks for asking, no I have a workbook with a number of "macro controlled" datasets which should be possible to be added to and deleted from a number of "macro controlled" charts. If a dataset is deleted from the workbook, I delete it from the charts first, but if this chart is now empty (seriescollection.count=0) and I delete the dataset which was in that chart before from the workbook, it shows that message. So there seems to remain some "unidentified contend" from the dataset in the chart.
I tracked it down to the simple Excel effect... it's definitely no VBA-issue

Comment: I have these 2 possibilities in mind at the moment:
1) defined name when you create the series in the code and there's ref to this name
2) Multiple worksheets - another chart exists that referencing to the same data series.  
You could create a backup and start removing worksheets to test for 2)

Comment: How about just leaving at least one series in every chart? Maybe a "hidden" series, for example by hiding a column containing the series data.

Comment: To help others you could selfanswer your question. This way someone else can find the solution you found.